# xtab/supertabular inserts column break if column starts with section header

Tags: two-column, supertabular, xtab

### Background information

I am creating a book with thousands of recipes in a two-column layout. The tables with the ingredients can be short, but can also be fairly long, so I like the tables to break.

### The problem

When a column starts with a chapter/section/subsection header, it induces a columnbreak, leaving large parts of the page empty.

[image]

### What I tried so far

The usual, I tried different document classes, e.g. scrbook, article. I tried using different packages and their respective environments, such as supertabular and xtab. Longtable is not working in two-column layout. I also tried different compilers, i.e. XeLaTeX (which I commonly use) and pdfLaTeX. I also removed every styling, makros (added some again for the mwe), and fonts.  Nothing worked so far.

### MWE

```
    \documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{xtab}

\newcommand{\dummytable}{
    \begin{xtabular}{rrl}
        stuff like ingredients & 5 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 3 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 15 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 1000 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 3 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 15 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 1000 & g \\ 
        \end{xtabular}
}

\newcommand{\dummytext}{This is some dummy text to reproduce my problem.}

\begin{document}

\section*{\textbf{1}: NUTRIENT AGAR}

\dummytable

\section*{\textbf{1a}: REACTIVATION WITH LIQUID MEDIUM 1}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{2}: BACILLUS PASTEURII MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\subsection*{Main sol. 1}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{3}: AZOTOBACTER MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{6}: ALLANTOIN MINERAL MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\section*{\textbf{7}: ANCYLOBACTER - SPIROSOMA MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{8}: BACILLUS "RACEMILACTICUS" MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{9}: VY/2 AGAR}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{9a}: VY/2, REDUCED MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{10}: ZYMOMONAS MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{11}: MRS MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{11a}: MODIFIED MEDIUM 11}

\dummytext

\subsection*{Main sol. 11}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{11b}: MRS MEDIUM (pre-reduced)}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{12}: SOIL EXTRACT MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext


\section*{\textbf{1}: NUTRIENT AGAR}

\dummytable

\section*{\textbf{1a}: REACTIVATION WITH LIQUID MEDIUM 1}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{2}: BACILLUS PASTEURII MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\subsection*{Main sol. 1}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{3}: AZOTOBACTER MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{6}: ALLANTOIN MINERAL MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\section*{\textbf{7}: ANCYLOBACTER - SPIROSOMA MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{8}: BACILLUS "RACEMILACTICUS" MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{9}: VY/2 AGAR}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{9a}: VY/2, REDUCED MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{10}: ZYMOMONAS MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{11}: MRS MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{11a}: MODIFIED MEDIUM 11}

\dummytext

\subsection*{Main sol. 11}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{11b}: MRS MEDIUM (pre-reduced)}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{12}: SOIL EXTRACT MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{1}: NUTRIENT AGAR}

\dummytable

\section*{\textbf{1a}: REACTIVATION WITH LIQUID MEDIUM 1}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{2}: BACILLUS PASTEURII MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\subsection*{Main sol. 1}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{3}: AZOTOBACTER MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{6}: ALLANTOIN MINERAL MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\section*{\textbf{7}: ANCYLOBACTER - SPIROSOMA MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{8}: BACILLUS "RACEMILACTICUS" MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{9}: VY/2 AGAR}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{9a}: VY/2, REDUCED MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{10}: ZYMOMONAS MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{11}: MRS MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{11a}: MODIFIED MEDIUM 11}

\dummytext

\subsection*{Main sol. 11}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{11b}: MRS MEDIUM (pre-reduced)}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{12}: SOIL EXTRACT MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\end{document}
```

Comment: You may also try `longtblr` environment from [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package.

Answer (score 0):

The provided example didn't produce the space shown but it did show a bad page break after a section heading.

Ideally one woul modify the table macros not to allow a page break at that point but simpler is to use the  `needspace` package to check that section headings do not fall too low on the page.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{xtab,needspace}

\newcommand{\dummytable}{\par\nopagebreak
    \begin{xtabular}{p{.35\textwidth}rl}
        stuff like ingredients & 5 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 3 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 15 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 1000 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 3 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 15 & g \\ 
        stuff like ingredients & 1000 & g \\ 
        \end{xtabular}%
}

\newcommand{\dummytext}{This is some dummy text to reproduce my problem.}

\begin{document}

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{1}: NUTRIENT AGAR}

\dummytable

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{1a}: REACTIVATION WITH LIQUID MEDIUM 1}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{2}: BACILLUS PASTEURII MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\subsection*{Main sol. 1}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{3}: AZOTOBACTER MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\section*{\textbf{6}: A\needspace{10\baselineskip}LLANTOIN MINERAL MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{7}: ANCYLOBACTER - SPIROSOMA MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{8}: BACILLUS "RACEMILACTICUS" MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{9}: VY/2 AGAR}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{9a}: VY/2, REDUCED MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{10}: ZYMOMONAS MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{11}: MRS MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{11a}: MODIFIED MEDIUM 11}

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\subsection*{Main sol. 11}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{11b}: MRS MEDIUM (pre-reduced)}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\needspace{10\baselineskip}\section*{\textbf{12}: SOIL EXTRACT MEDIUM}

\dummytable

\dummytext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efford! As I indicated in my question, the MWE did produce the result shown on the image. However, when I run the compilation multiple times, I get the column break on different positions and sometime even none. The longer the document, the higher the possibility that column breaks occur. The original doc contains >700 pages and a large number of unwanted breaks. needspace does not fix this.

Comment: @JKoblitz no that MWE doesn't have different page breaks on different runs, were you trying a version with `\tableofcontents` that would change after the first run.

Comment: I updated the MWE to be more reproducible. I also added an updated image of the result after three compilation runs. No tableofcontents. It is the exact same code that I posted above.

Comment: @JKoblitz thanks.